# selection of features using PCA

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, pca

I am doing unsupervised classification. For this I have 8 features (Variance of Green, Std. div. of Green , Mean of Red, Variance of Red, Std. div. of Red, Mean of Hue, Variance of Hue, Std. div. of Hue) for classification per image and I want to select 3 most significant features using PCA. I have written the following code for feature selection
(where dimension of feature is : 179X8) :

```
for c=1:size(feature,1)
   feature(c,:)=feature(c,:)-mean(feature)
end

DataCov=cov(feature); % covariance matrix
[PC,variance,explained] = pcacov(DataCov)
```

This gives me :

PC =

```
0.0038   -0.0114    0.0517    0.0593    0.0039    0.3998    0.9085   -0.0922
0.0755   -0.1275    0.6339    0.6824   -0.3241   -0.0377   -0.0641    0.0052
0.7008    0.7113   -0.0040    0.0496   -0.0207    0.0042    0.0012    0.0002
0.0007   -0.0012    0.0051    0.0101    0.0272    0.0288    0.0873    0.9953
0.0320   -0.0236    0.1521    0.2947    0.9416   -0.0142   -0.0289   -0.0266
0.7065   -0.6907   -0.1282   -0.0851    0.0060    0.0003    0.0010   -0.0001
0.0026   -0.0037    0.0632   -0.0446    0.0053    0.9125   -0.4015    0.0088
0.0543   -0.0006    0.7429   -0.6574    0.0838   -0.0705    0.0311   -0.0001
```

variance =

```
0.0179
0.0008
0.0001
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
```

explained =

```
94.9471
4.1346
0.6616
0.2358
0.0204
0.0003
0.0002
0.0000
```

This means first  principle component has 94.9% variance explained and so on ... but these are in order of  most to least significant. 
How can I know which features (from 1 to 8) to be selected based on above information.

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste the content of your `feature` variable to somewhere on the net such as http://codepaste.net/ and share the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the same as the COLUMNSELECT problem discussed by Mahoney and Drineas in ["CUR matrix decompositions for improved data analysis"](http://www.pnas.org/content/106/3/697.abstract).

They first compute the leverage scores for each dimension and then selects 3 of them randomly using the leverage scores as weights. Alternatively, you can select the largest ones. Here's the script for your problem:

I first got a real nature image from the web and resized it to the dimensions you ask. The image is as follows:

[image: img]

```
%# Example data from real image of size 179x8
%# You can skip it for your own data
features = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('img.png')));

%# m samples, n dimensions
[m,n] = size(features);
```

Then, compute the centralized data:

```
%# Remove the mean
features = features - repmat(mean(features,2), 1, size(features,2));
```

I use SVD to compute PCA since it gives you both the principal components and the coefficients. If the samples are in columns, then `U` holds the principal components. Check the second page of [this paper](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/4000/pdf/imm4000.pdf) for the relationship.

```
%# Compute the SVD
[U,S,V] = svd(features);
```

The key idea here is that we want to get the dimensions having most of the variation. And an assumption is that there's some noise in data. We select only the dominant eigenvectors, e.g. representing the 95% of the data.

```
%# Compute the number of eigenvectors representing
%#  the 95% of the variation
coverage = cumsum(diag(S));
coverage = coverage ./ max(coverage);
[~, nEig] = max(coverage > 0.95);
```

Then the leverage scores are computed using `nEig` of the principal components. That is, we take the norm of the `nEig` coefficients.

```
%# Compute the norms of each vector in the new space
norms = zeros(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    norms(i) = norm(V(i,1:nEig))^2;
end
```

Then, we can sort the leverage scores:

```
%# Get the largest 3
[~, idx] = sort(norms);
idx(1:3)'
```

and get the indices of the vectors with the largest leverage scores:

```
ans =
   6     8     5
```

You can check the paper for more details.

But, keep in mind that PCA-based technique is good if you have many many dimensions. In your case, the search space is very small. My advice is to search exhaustively in the space and get the best selection as @amit recommends.

Comment: @ petrichor. I have features which were extracted from certain region of Interest in an Image for eg. I have image with different vessels and on each of these vessels I have extracted features on the centreline pixels of the vessels. As you described above , your feature matrix is an image not the features from certain region of interest. I want to know if your method still applicable in my case

Comment: @Dev My example is just a toy meaningless example that shows how to implement it in MATLAB. It actually is meaningful in your case.

Answer (score 3):

PCA is actually generating a set of new features, each is a linear transformation from the original elements.

Thus, the vector you get cannot directly be translated to the features you need to chose in order to get this variance- it just creates a new feature based on the originals.

In your case, you get:

```
New_Feature = 0.038*F1 + 0.0755*F2 + 0.7008*F3 + ... + 0.0543*F8
```

This `New_Feature` gives you 94.9471% information gain, despite the dimensionality reduction.

(And if you do the same for the next principle comopnents and use them as well, you obviously increase your information gain)

If you need to get a subset of the originals, and not create new features - I would have used other methods instead of PCA.

Genetic Algorithms are usually pretty good for subset selection, and if your set of features only include 8 features - you could also consider brute force search  - there are only 2<sup>8</sup>=256 possible subsets. It might be possible in some cases to try all subsets and see what gives you the best performance.

Comment: @ amit. Thankyou for your reply. I am using unsupervised classification i.e. I dont have trainning data set. As per my knowlegde I can not use Genetic Algorithm (GA) as it require training data set. Pls. correct me if I am wrong. I mean, can I use GA for unsupervised classification?

Comment: @Dev: do you mean clustering? If so, maybe you can find clusters using all features - and take it the the ground truth, and use GA or other subset selection algorithm to find a subset which is close enough to it. Or, you can stick to PCA - but be aware that you are getting "new features" and not a subset of the original features.

Answer (score 1):

From the [pcacov docs](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/pcacov.html):

> COEFF is a p-by-p matrix, with each column containing coefficients for one principal component. The columns are in order of decreasing component variance.

Since `explained` shows that only the first component really contributes a significant amount to explained variance, you should look at the first column of `PC` to see which original features it uses:

```
0.0038
0.0755
0.7008 <---
0.0007 
0.0320 
0.7065 <---
0.0026 
0.0543
```

It turns out, in your example, that the 3rd and 6th features (indicated with <-- ) are the main contributors to the first principal components. You could say that these features are the most important ones.

Similarly, based on the fact that the 1st, 4th and 7th features only get large weights in some of the last columns of `PC`, one could conclude that they are relatively unimportant.

However, for this sort of per-feature analysis, PCA might not be the best fit; you could derive such information from the standard deviations of the original features just as well.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but could you elaborate the last sentence. I didnt understod how to sort feature from standard deviation.... Thanks in advance